# Cannot run Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I have been building my Android application for 2 years and I have never once had this problem until now.

When I load Eclipse, there is a little progress bar in the bottom right corner of the window which says "Android Library Update."  If you click on it, a tab opens up called "Progress" and shows you what is going on.

[image: Here is what it shows]

This has been sitting here not moving for the last 20 minutes.  If I attempt to run the project, Eclipse freezes and I have to force quit it.  If I do nothing, nothing happens.  I am completely stuck and cannot work.

The only thing I can think of which may be relevant is that earlier this morning I was working with no internet connection (I was somewhere else without wifi).  I obviously have a connection now (I am writing this post).

If I turn off wifi and launch Eclipse with no internet connection, everything works fine.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could tell, this solved the problem:

1. Disable internet connection.  In my case, this simply meant turning off wireless.
2. Launch Eclipse.  Everything will load fine.
3. Re-enable internet.
4. Close Eclipse.

Now opening Eclipse is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The First thing I do is

- make sure you save your project and all it's resources in a different location to keep it safe if something goes wrong, this is a good idea in general (personally i use drop box so that even if something gets worse i can still recover it)
- Try closing eclipse and starting again, if you get the chance try it while plugged into your router with a **Ethernet** wire.
- Make sure to check that Eclipse is up to date so that there are definitively no conflicts.
- If this doesn't work try un-installing and re-installing eclipse.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly today I'm having the same issue, except I don't have a `Android Library Update` message, turning off internet also helped start the project for me:

[image]

I opened up WireShark to investigate why it was relying on an internet connection at startup and I found it was making some HTTP call to `http://developer.android.com/reference/`

[image]

Adding the following line to my `/etc/hosts` file allows me to start up the project with the internet on:

```
127.0.0.1       developer.android.com
```