# How do you disable Android Library Update?

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there any way to disable automatic Android Library Update when starting Eclipse?

Comment: What "automatic Android Library Update in Eclipse"?

Comment: ADT does not automatically update itself. So, again, what "automatic Android Library Update in Eclipse" are you referring to?

Comment: The one related to the "Android Library Update" message shown in the progressbar at the bottom when starting Eclipse.  Described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089262/cannot-run-android-project, but the solution there is not very practical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The one related to the "Android Library Update" message shown in the progressbar at the bottom when starting Eclipse

AFAIK, there is no way to disable it, and even if there is, your projects probably would not work afterwards.

However, you can reduce the amount of time spent on this and other startup tasks. Simply close projects that you do not need to have open. You can leave the projects in the workspace, but just close them via right-clicking on the project in the Package Explorer and choosing "Close Project".

My Eclipse workspace has ~350 Android projects. It used to take a minor eternity to fire up Eclipse in the morning. I switched to keeping most projects closed, leaving open only:

- stuff I am working on
- all Android library projects (in case stuff I am working on, now or later, depends upon them)
- stuff I opened earlier and haven't gotten around to closing again yet

I have a few dozen projects open at the moment. Now, Eclipse starts up fairly quickly.

Comment: I guess there's no good way around this automatic operation; thanks.