# How to get rid from Android Library Update?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

Whenever I start my eclipse, it always try to upload the Android Library it self. Please see the following screenshot,

> [image]

I am sure you too encountered the same thing. The thing is that sometime it takes too much time to update and till that time we can not use the eclipse.

What setting do I need to do to stop this process ?

Answer (score 0):

The library auto-update for your project cannot be disabled. You can either reduce unnecessary library in your project or close the projects that are not used in the workplace. There are different approaches.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14389817/2777098

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13123572/2777098

Comment: The change will be in effect the next time you start Eclipse. Here is a reference from Eclipse User Guide: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-p2-autoupdate.htm

Comment: Of course after restart. I checked it with restarting the eclipse.

Comment: I see what you mean now. The library update in your project cannot be disabled.